# VBA Inserting rows with content and editing prior and preciding rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am inserting data into a SQL database from Excel. I cannot use Bulk Upload as the data is not on the server, I also do not have access to SSIS. I have VBA code to insert into the database directly from Excel but I have a number of data sources and would like to have one SQL Query to insert all of the data.

I have processed the data and using the CONCATENATE function presented it for copying into SQL but there is a 1,000 row limit so I have produced the following code (below) to insert two rows every 1,000 rows with the required SQL statements included.

I now need to select the row before the INSERT statement and add a semi-colon to the end of the text and select the row after the VALUES statement and remove the leading comma.

Could anyone assist?

```
Sub SQLInsert()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet7.Name)

LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1000
Rows(i).Insert
Range("A" & i).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "VALUES"
Rows(i).Insert
Range("A" & i).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "INSERT INTO data.Table (A,B,C,D)"
Next i

End Sub
```

I am relatively new to VBA so please correct my code if there are any errors or bad practise.

EDIT: 
After using R3UK's code below there is one error. After running the code I find that the cell below VALUES contains two records. For example:
If values was inserted above row 10 which contained: ,(Box)
and row 11 contained: ,(Cup)
The row under values would now contain: (Box)Cup)
All other rows are fine.

In addition, the code adds INSERT and VALUES rows just one above the last data row in my sheet. This is not a problem but not efficient, any recommendation to prevent this?

EDIT: Below I have included three screenshots of the VBA code I am running, the before with relevant cells highlighted and an after showing the error.

[image: vba script]

[image: Before running script]

[image: After running script]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I got rid of the `Select` which are ressource greedy and not useful in widely most of the code you'll see.

Then I added the code to remove comma (2 versions in same code, pick yours) and to add a semi-colon :

```
Sub SQLInsert()
Dim sht As Worksheet, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    TempStart As String, _
    TempEnd As String, _
    TempCell As String


Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet7.Name)

LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count


For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1000
    sht.Cells(i , 1) = CStr(CStr(sht.Cells(i , 1)) & ";")
    'String variable to improve code efficiency
    TempCell = CStr(sht.Cells(i + 1, 1))
    If InStr(1, TempCell, ",") Then
        'Hardcore version : (if there is more than one "," it will delete all of them)
        'TempCell = Replace(TempCell, ",", "")

        'Clean version :
        If InStr(1, TempCell, ",") <> Len(TempCell) Then
            TempStart = Left(TempCell, InStr(1, TempCell, ",") + 1)
            TempEnd = Replace(TempCell, TempStart, "")
            TempStart = Replace(TempStart, ",", "")
            sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = CStr(TempStart & TempEnd) 
        Else
            sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Left(TempCell, Len(TempCell) - 1)
        End If
    Else
        'Didn't find a comma in that cell
    End If

    DoEvents
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
    Range("A" & i + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "VALUES"
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
    Range("A" & i + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "INSERT INTO data.Table (A,B,C,D)"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not insert another line and just put a semi on it?

Comment: Indeed that would work too, but I think the `Rows.Insert` will be longer that just working with a cell content

Comment: As Keiran mention in his attempt to edit my answer, the initial proposal I made was removing comma a row to low. So it is corrected in this edit and  @Rossco : I added a string to work with, which would be better than a cell for efficiency

Comment: @R3uK: The inserts are working but neither the semi-colon or comma operation is working, I presume it is to do with the string variable?

Comment: Nope nothing to do with the string. Not working at all? I don't get how the semi-colon can't work... How is your data? Only in first column? If not, plz provide explanation or screenshot (if possible of input and output) by editing your question and write in the comment of my answer so that I can be notified, thx

Comment: @R3uK The problem was my fault, I had renamed sheets and it was doing the inserts in one sheet and the punctuation in another for some reason. I have resolved this with a fresh workbook. However there is a different problem which I have described at the bottom of my original question. I have tried to include screenshots but StackOverflow is throwing up an error.

Comment: That is an odd problem... No clue were it is coming from... For the sheet, you can call directly with the name like this `Sheets("Sheet_Name")`. Let me know if that strange combo is still happening with the new version (corrected index to insert at the right place and added DoEvents)

Comment: @R3uK I have added some screenshots to demonstrate the error.

Comment: My bad, I used the wrong string in `TempStart = Replace(TempCell, ",", "")` that in fact needs to be `TempStart = Replace(TempStart, ",", "")`
It's corrected and should work perfectly now! ;)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understood you completly as i have no sql experience and i'm still a VBA novice myself, but if i did understand you, you want:
1 - adding a semi colon to the text
2 - remove a comma that is the first charcter in a string

so, you can add by simply selecting the specific cell and appending like this

```
Cells(rw,cl).Value = Cells(rw,cl).Value & ";"
```

where rw is the row number and cl is the column number (you can also use the letter i.e. "A")

and remove the leading comma by manipulating the string like this:

```
Cells(rw,cl).Value = Mid(Cells(rw,cl).Value,2)
```